# Using DTD can I specify an exact number of element occurrences?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am trying to do this exercise in XML and I am stuck at this particular point. I am being asked to create a DTD that will satisfy a list of requirements and I cannot find a way to achieve the following:

> The seasonal_prices' list can have none, one, two or three occurrences of the 'season_price' element

Is there a way to achieve this using ***only*** a DTD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this using ***only*** a DTD?

Nope.

You can only do:

- `season_price` (exactly one)
- `season_price?` (zero or one)
- `season_price+` (one or more)
- `season_price*` (zero or more)

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-element-content for more info.

----- **Edit** -----

Like you mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272296/using-only-a-dtd-are-there-any-disadvantages-in-limiting-the-number-of-children), you *could* do this using `?` like:

```
<!ELEMENT seasonal_prices (season_price?, season_price?, season_price?)>
```

but there's no direct way like in XML Schema (minOccurs/maxOccurs).

Comment: Just as I suspected. Thanks for the confirmation Daniel!